# How to show link in autocomplete

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to show link for my autocomplete
my code is

```
   $("#search-header").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "Search",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {
                            name: request.term,
                            maxRows: 12
                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.atomList, function (item) {
                                console.log(item);
                                return {
                                    label: "<a href=" + item.id + ">" + item.name + "</a>",
                                    value: item.id
                                }
                            }));
                        },
                        error: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                            console.log(typeof data);
                            console.log(data);
                            alert('error');
                        }
                    });
          },.....
```

It is showing output like 
`<a>Text</a>`
not the link how to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use renderItem

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  $("#search-header").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      //to simulate a async ajax request
      setTimeout(function() {
        var data = {
          atomList: [{
            id: '1',
            name: 'v-1'
          }]
        }
        response($.map(data.atomList, function(item) {
          return {
            label: item.name,
            value: item.id
          }
        }));
      })
    }
  }).data('uiAutocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
      .append("<a href=" + item.id + ">" + item.value + "</a>")
      .appendTo(ul);
  };
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="search-header" />
```

Comment: Won't work for jQuery 2+, see my answer for an alternative (http://jsfiddle.net/s4s49fqw/)

Comment: @JohnC yes in 2+ the data key is changed to `ui-autocomplete` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zLmpqfm5/3/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Unable to configure for this please see https://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/5s510cL7/ where which data to add not getting. I am using jquery 2.1

Answer (score 0):

You want to use autocompletes' [`_renderItem`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem) which allows you to define how your autocomplete list is displayed.  Unlike Arun's answer my `_renderItem` is inside the autocomplete declaration which makes it a little more readable.

```
$("#search-header").autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response
    $.ajax({
      url: "Search",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        name: request.term,
        maxRows: 12
      },
      success: function (data) {
        response($.map(data.atomList, function (item) {
          console.log(item);
          return {
            label: "<a href=" + item.id + ">" + item.name + "</a>",
            value: item.id
          }
        }));
      },
      error: function (data) {
        alert(data);
        console.log(typeof data);
        console.log(data);
        alert('error');
      },
      _renderItem: function (ul, item) {
        return $("<li></li>")
          .data("value", item)
          .append(item.label)
          .appendTo(ul);
      }
    });
},.....
```